# pthread and main thread are running on same core by default in cygwin?

Tags: c, multithreading, cygwin

I'm using multi-core machine, and tried to run this simple code few times:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <unistd.h>

int evenCounter = 0;

int nextEven()
{
    ++evenCounter;
    ++evenCounter;
    return evenCounter;
}

void* pThreadFunction()
{
    int i, val;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        val = nextEven();
        printf("*** increase from pThread - new Value is: %d\n", val);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void main(){
    pthread_t pThread;
    int i, val;
    if (pthread_create(&pThread, NULL, pThreadFunction, NULL) != 0) 
    {
        puts("failed to create print thread");
        return 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        val = nextEven();
        printf("increase from main - new Value is: %d\n", val);
    }
}
```

And got results like those all the time:

```
increase from main - new Value is: 2
*** increase from pThread - new Value is: 4
increase from main - new Value is: 6
*** increase from pThread - new Value is: 8
increase from main - new Value is: 10
*** increase from pThread - new Value is: 12
increase from main - new Value is: 14
*** increase from pThread - new Value is: 16
increase from main - new Value is: 18
*** increase from pThread - new Value is: 20
increase from main - new Value is: 22
*** increase from pThread - new Value is: 24
increase from main - new Value is: 26
*** increase from pThread - new Value is: 28
increase from main - new Value is: 30
*** increase from pThread - new Value is: 32
```

(The order between the first printings was different sometimes, but the values were the same).
If those two threads run on different cores - I would expect some wrong values (like odd values) in the printings, so for my understanding - those threads run on the same core.

Is it really like that in cygwin?
And if it is, how can I make main thread and the pthread run on different cores?
I saw an option for using `sched_setaffinity` , but it doesn't work in cygwin.

Comment: You have data race in the access/update to `evenCounter`.

Comment: 8 attempts is not enough to lose a race condition. Try a few million times. Especially since the printing you do takes at least a few tens of thousands times more time than the bit with the race.  Also, you do have a hidden lock in your code that synchronises the threads. Printf, or whatever it prints to has a lock and that accidentally synchronizes your threads.

Comment: @Art, I tried a lot more then 8 times, but used a small number here only for simplicity. Also, I edited my code - now I'm taking the value of nextEven() before the call to printf, so no mutex in here as far as I know (but still getting same results).

Comment: To properly see if race happens: increment a global variable 500 million times in a thread. Increment the same global variable 500 million times in the main thread. Check if the value of the global variable is a billion. That should start getting close to reliable race condition territory. Most likely, your two increments are just replaced by one addition by two by the compiler because the compiler doesn't want to waste time.